# Calculating input resistance of Darlington pair (TIP120) from datasheet values

Tags: resistance, darlington

I've tried to find a way to calculate the input resistance of a Darlington pair ([TIP120](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP120-D.PDF)), using the values given in the datasheets.

After searching for a while, I was only able to find solutions for discrete Darlingtons; these required knowing parameters for each transistor (like the hfe and hie that are missing in the TIP120 datasheet).

I need these parameters to perform the calculations concerning the AC analysis of this circuit (T1 is the Darlington):

[image]

How do I find Hfe and Hfi for this circuit?

Comment: The circuit you posted has three transistors with no power supply. They will do nothing without a power supply.

Answer (score 1):

> After Searching for a while, i was only able to find solutions for
>   discrete darlingtons,(these required knowing parameters for each
>   transistor (like the hfe,hie that are missing in tip120 datasheet).

The data sheet is particularly good for this device. Here are a few snippets: -

[image]

Given that hIE is the input impedance and hFE is both stated and graphed I'm not sure you are looking deeply enough at the data sheet.

> I need this parameter to perform the calculations concerning the AC
>   Analysis of this circuit

As with virtually any analysis I would urge you to use a simulator to double check any hand calculations you may make. Sims are free and good (usually) and far more accurate than a hand-calculation.